# Programatically create a Popup with a Child element initialised by Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

`Windows.Media.Captures` has a handy `CameraCaptureUI` class that can be instantiated as follows to show a dialog to the user to capture photos or videos:

```
// Create dialog to Capture Video
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
dialog.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;

StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);
if (file != null)
{
   // Do something with file...
}
```

I would like to create my own custom audio capture class that works in a very similar way:

```
// Create dialog to Capture Audio
AudioCaptureUI dialog = new AudioCaptureUI();

StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
   // Do something with file...
}
```

To do the above, I created the following three files:

- `AudioCaptureUI` - The class that a user instantiates to show the audio capture dialog
- `AudioCaptureView` - UI View for the audio capture experience
- `AudioCaptureViewModel` - ViewModel that contains all the audio capture logic

To create a full screen audio capture dialog, I have figured out that the best way is to use a `Popup` and set its child to the `AudioCaptureView`. The problem I have with this approach is that it is pushing me use a View-First pattern. Since I am using Caliburn Micro, I wanted to be able to use CM to instantiate a View by creating the ViewModel first.

What I currently have is something on the following lines:

```
public class AudioCaptureUI
{
    private Popup _popup;
    private TaskCompletionSource<StorageFile> _taskCompletionSource;

    public IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> CaptureFileAsync()
    {
        // Force my View to be full screen
        AudioCaptureView audioCaptureView = new AudioCaptureView
        {
            Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width,
            Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height
        };

        // Creating View, instead of a ViewModel. Renders Caliburn Micro useless!
        _popup = new Popup { Child = audioCaptureView };

        if (_popup.Child != null)
        {
            SubscribeEvents();
            _popup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        return AsyncInfo.Run(WaitForInput);
    }

    ...
}
```

The above pattern works. However, I am forced to wire all my actions manually and cannot leverage Caliburn Micro's MVVM goodness.

How else should I instantiate a ViewModel programatically from my `AudioCaptureUI` class?

It is also important to highlight that I am working on a **Windows Store app** and using the WinRT CM port.

Comment: You could just call the CM binding mechanism to bind up the view/model after you've instantiated them. It can still glue everything together - `WindowManager` does this. It's worth looking at the source for some clues. Essentially the code you are most interested in is probably `ViewModelBinder.Bind(rootModel, view, context);`, you can see it and the surrounding wire-up here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/sl4/WindowManager.cs. I'd imagine rolling your own framework component to do this wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Because I am using CM for Windows Store app, the Window Manager is not available. Thanks for pointing me towards the `ViewModelBinder` class. That is indeed very promising and could potentially be what I am after. Will test it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always port the WindowManager to WinRT in your own project. Looking at the source I don't think too much will need to change.  https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/net40/WindowManager.cs

You could bring over the Interface as well and use DI but for the sake of time here is the stand alone class. The main part for Model first binding is the `ViewLocator.LocateForModel` which returns the View from the ViewModel (aka the magic)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Caliburn.Micro
{
    public class WindowManager
    {    
        public virtual void ShowPopup(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            var popup = CreatePopup(rootModel, settings);
            var view = ViewLocator.LocateForModel(rootModel, popup, context);

            popup.Child = view;
            //popup.SetValue(View.IsGeneratedProperty, true);

            ViewModelBinder.Bind(rootModel, popup, null);
            Caliburn.Micro.Action.SetTargetWithoutContext(view, rootModel);

            var activatable = rootModel as IActivate;
            if (activatable != null)
            {
                activatable.Activate();
            }

            var deactivator = rootModel as IDeactivate;
            if (deactivator != null)
            {
                popup.Closed += delegate { deactivator.Deactivate(true); };
            }

            popup.IsOpen = true;
            //popup.CaptureMouse();
        }

        protected virtual Popup CreatePopup(object rootModel, IDictionary<string, object> settings)
        {
            var popup = new Popup();

            ApplySettings(popup, settings);

            return popup;
        }

        bool ApplySettings(object target, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> settings)
        {
            if (settings != null)
            {
                var type = target.GetType();

                foreach (var pair in settings)
                {
                    var propertyInfo = type.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(pair.Key);

                    if (propertyInfo != null)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(target, pair.Value, null);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is create an instance and give it a ViewModel:

```
var windowManager = new WindowManager();
windowManager.ShowPopup(new MyPopupThingViewModel());
```

Note: I've only used this in an 8.1 app so not 100% sure if it will completely work with 8.0

Comment: Write answer. Porting the WindowsManager is pretty much what I was after. The only thing that I would point out is that you do need to uncomment `popup.SetValue(View.IsGeneratedProperty, true);`.

Comment: For those interested in making their popup full screen, you can override `OnViewLoaded` in your ViewModel and set the view width/height being passed to the dimensions of `Window.Current.Bounds`.

Comment: Good to see it worked for you. Should probably submit this as a Pull Request to the Caliburn.Micro project on codeplex.

Comment: PR has been sent so WindowManager should be included in the win8/win81 packages sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success with the `Caliburn.Micro` `WindowManager`. There isn't a great deal about it in the official documentation (you're best off searching Google and the CM discussions). I've used it in one of my applications where I needed to host a particular `ViewModel` in a new window, and wanted to utilise all of the `Caliburn.Micro` goodness (and my existing `Views`).

Have a look at the `Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager` interface, you'll see some handy methods that you can call from a WindowManager instance (depending on the popup type you're after).

```
public interface IWindowManager
{
    bool? ShowDialog(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
    void ShowPopup(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
    void ShowWindow(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
}
```

In my application, to pop up my a Window with my `ViewModel` of choice, I did something along these lines (your names inserted):

```
// Some basic Window settings.
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.Title = "Test Window";
settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
settings.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
settings.Width = 450;
settings.Height = 300;

var localAudioCaptureViewModel new AudioCaptureViewModel ();
WindowManagerFactory.WindowManager.ShowWindow(localAudioCaptureViewModel, null, settings); // I didn't require context (null)
```

Caliburn.Micro should resolve your Views to the correct ViewModels, and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi Chris. Appreciate your response. What I failed to include in my question (and will update it shortly) is that I am working on a Windows Store app (i.e. Winrt). I'm pretty sure the CM Winrt port does not include the WindowManager of the IWindowManager interface